# Auto Play Full Screen Background Slider

Tags: jquery, html, background, fullscreen

I'm using a Full-screen background jquery slider for a website, which is by default in **Pause** state.

I tried playing around with the jQuery but it didn't quite worked for me.

I also tried to use trigger method to override the current pause state by click the 'play' button after page load

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
  $('a#play, a.play').trigger('click');
});
```

but that didn't worked too...

I'm pasting the jQuery script below that possibly does the action

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('body').append('<span id="body_loader"></span>');
    $('#body_loader').fadeIn(); 

//In our jQuery function, we will first cache some element and define some variables:
var $bg             = $('#background'),
    $bg_img         = $bg.find('img'),
    $bg_img_eq      = $bg_img.eq(0),
    total           = $bg_img.length,
    current         = 0,
    $next       = $('#next'),
    $prev       = $('#prev')

$(window).load(function(){
    //hide loader
    $('#body_loader').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        init();
    }).remove(); 

});

var intervalID,
    play = $('#play'),
    titleItem = $('.title-item');   

//shows the first image and initializes events
function init(){
    //get dimentions for the image, based on the windows size
    var dim = getImageDim($bg_img_eq);
    //set the returned values and show the image
    $bg_img_eq.css({
        width   : dim.width,
        height  : dim.height,
        left    : dim.left,
        top    : dim.top
    }).fadeIn('normal');

    //resizing the window resizes the $tf_bg_img
    $(window).bind('resize',function(){
        var dim = getImageDim($bg_img_eq);
        $bg_img_eq.css({
            width   : dim.width,
            height  : dim.height,
            left    : dim.left,
            top     : dim.top
        });
    });

    var activeTitle = $bg_img_eq.attr('title');
        titleItem.html(activeTitle);
        titleItem.html(function(){
            var text= $(this).text().split(" ");
            var last = text.pop();
            return text.join(" ")+ (text.length > 0 ? " <span class='word-last'>"+ last + "</span>" : last);
        });

    play.bind('click', function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('pause')) {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            $(this).removeClass('pause').addClass('play');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('pause').removeClass('play');
            intervalID = setInterval("$('#next').trigger('click')", 10000);
        }

    });

    //click the arrow down, scrolls down
    $next.bind('click',function(){
        if($bg_img_eq.is(':animated'))
            return false;
            scroll('tb');
    });

    //click the arrow up, scrolls up
    $prev.bind('click',function(){
        if($bg_img_eq.is(':animated'))
        return false;
        scroll('bt');
    });
}
```

The class & id of div which holds the images is `background` and play button class and id is `play`.

The link of the template that i'm working on http://xhtml.webtemplatemasters.com/style/dark/index.html#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your general.js file

```
play.trigger('click');
```

And if it's Wordpress Template, then

```
if(slide_autostart){ 
play.trigger('click'); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can also use this plugin.

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

[DEMO](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html)